# How do they define $r(x;\xi)$, $p(x|y;\xi)$,$Pr(A|y;\xi)$

Tags: information-theory, information-geometry

I am reading Methods of Information Geometry by  Shun-ichi Amari and Hiroshi Nagaoka.
In section 2.2 The Fisher metric, I do not understand the notions $r(x;\xi)$, $p(x|y;\xi)$, $\mathrm{Pr}(A|y;\xi)$, how are they defined?
If $r(x;\xi)= p(x;\xi)/q(F(x);\xi)$ then $p(x|y;\xi)=r(x;\xi)\delta_{F(x)}(y)$, how is it getting ?

[image]

Here is my try :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I will drop the $\xi$ to simplify the notation.

You are correct that $p(x|y) = \frac{p(x, y)}{q(y)}$, however from there you need to remember that $Y$ fully depends on $X$ since it is a function of $X$, so that if $X=x$, then $Y=F(x)$.

As such, the joint probability $p(x, y)$ is always zero unless $y=F(x)$, in which case the pair $(x, y)$ "matches". If they match, you can then write $p(x, y) = p(x, F(x)) = p(x)$. Combining those two observations yields $p(x, y)=p(x)\cdot\delta_{F(x)}(y)\quad\forall x, y$.

Using this in the conditional probability, you get
$$p(x|y) = \frac{p(x, y)}{q(y)} = \frac{p(x)\cdot\delta_{F(x)}(y)}{q(y)} = \frac{p(x)\cdot\delta_{F(x)}(y)}{q(F(x))}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am not getting how do you get if $(x,y)$ matches then $p(x,y|y=F(x))=p(x)$ ?

Comment: This is because you are conditioning on $y$ so the only randomness left comes from $x$.

Comment: Let me know if anything is still unclear, otherwise feel free to mark the answer as accepted ;)

Comment: Can you explain this with an example ? I am trying to do it by taking $X=-1,0,1$ with probability $1/2,1/3,1/6$ & $Y=X^2$.Then I got $P(x=1,y=1|y=1)=1/4 \neq p(1)$.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I was too fast in writing the answer, I just edited it!